# Unable to import data from CouchDB

Tags: json, couchdb, couchdb-futon

I am trying to import and then export data to a remote machine. Here goes the schema of the database. This is just a document that I got it in a form of json.

```
{"docs":[
{"id":"702decba698fea7df3fa46fdd9000fa4","key":"702decba698fea7df3fa46fdd9000fa4","value":{"rev":"1-f8c63611d5bc7354cac42d2a697ad57a"},"doc":{"_id":"702decba698fea7df3fa46fdd9000fa4","_rev":"1-f8c63611d5bc7354cac42d2a697ad57a","contributors":null,"truncated":false,"text":"RT @Whistlepodu4Csk: : First time since 1987 World Cup no Asian teams in the WC final\nThis had occurred in 1975, 1979, 1987 and now #CWC15\n…","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"id":583090814735155201,"favorite_count":0,"author":{"py/object":"tweepy.models.User","py/state":{"follow_request_sent":false,"profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_text_color":"333333","id":3102321084,"verified":false,"profile_location":null,"profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/579460416977252352/weSzVnPF_normal.jpg","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","is_translator":false,"geo_enabled":false,"entities":{"description":{"urls":[]}},"followers_count":1,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","id_str":"3102321084","default_profile_image":false,"location":"Chennai","is_translation_enabled":false,"utc_offset":null,"statuses_count":9,"description":"12/11","friends_count":23,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/579460416977252352/weSzVnPF_normal.jpg","notifications":false,"profile_background_image_url_https":"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","name":"charandevaa","lang":"en","profile_background_tile":false,"favourites_count":7,"screen_name":"charandevaarg","url":null,"created_at":{"py/object":"datetime.datetime","__reduce__":[{"py/type":"datetime.datetime"},["B98DFgEtLgAAAA=="]]},"contributors_enabled":false,"time_zone":null,"protected":false,"default_profile":true,"following":false,"listed_count":0}},"retweeted":false,"coordinates":null,"entities":{"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[{"indices":[3,19],"id_str":"570379002","screen_name":"Whistlepodu4Csk","name":"Chennai Super Kings","id":570379002}],"hashtags":[{"indices":[132,138],"text":"CWC15"},{"indices":[139,140],"text":"IndvsAus"}],"urls":[]},"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"id_str":"583090814735155201","retweet_count":9,"metadata":{"iso_language_code":"en","result_type":"recent"},"favorited":false,"retweeted_status":{"py/object":"tweepy.models.Status","py/state":{"contributors":null,"truncated":false,"text":": First time since 1987 World Cup no Asian teams in the WC final\nThis had occurred in 1975, 1979, 1987 and now #CWC15\n#IndvsAus\"","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"id":581059988317073409,"favorite_count":6,"author":{"py/object":"tweepy.models.User","py/state":{"follow_request_sent":false,"profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_text_color":"333333","id":570379002,"verified":false,"profile_location":null,"profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/460329225124188160/FgnIhlVM_normal.jpeg","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","is_translator":false,"geo_enabled":false,"entities":{"url":{"urls":[{"indices":[0,22],"url":"http://t.co/Kx3erXpkEJ","expanded_url":"http://chennaisuperkings.com","display_url":"chennaisuperkings.com"}]},"description":{"urls":[{"indices":[138,160],"url":"http://t.co/yfitkkfz5D","expanded_url":"http://www.facebook.com/chennaisuperkingsofficialfansclub","display_url":"facebook.com/chennaisuperki…"}]}},"followers_count":13604,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","id_str":"570379002","default_profile_image":false,"location":"Chennai","is_translation_enabled":false,"utc_offset":19800,"statuses_count":13107,"description":"Chennai super kings fans club:All about Mahi, Raina,Mccullum,Aswhin,Bravo. Updates about Suriya: Beleive in CSK: Whistlepodu!Suriya Rocks http://t.co/yfitkkfz5D","friends_count":11962,"profile_link_color":"CCC200","profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/460329225124188160/FgnIhlVM_normal.jpeg","notifications":false,"profile_background_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/518467484358164480/yUXQYv3m.jpeg","profile_background_color":"FFF04D","profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/570379002/1370113848","profile_background_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/518467484358164480/yUXQYv3m.jpeg","name":"Chennai Super Kings","lang":"en","profile_background_tile":true,"favourites_count":283,"screen_name":"Whistlepodu4Csk","url":"http://t.co/Kx3erXpkEJ","created_at":{"py/object":"datetime.datetime","__reduce__":[{"py/type":"datetime.datetime"},["B9wFAxUWFAAAAA=="]]},"contributors_enabled":false,"time_zone":"Chennai","protected":false,"default_profile":false,"following":false,"listed_count":23}},"retweeted":false,"coordinates":null,"entities":{"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[],"hashtags":[{"indices":[111,117],"text":"CWC15"},{"indices":[118,127],"text":"IndvsAus"}],"urls":[]},"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"id_str":"581059988317073409","retweet_count":9,"metadata":{"iso_language_code":"en","result_type":"recent"},"favorited":false,"source_url":"http://twitter.com/download/android","user":{"py/id":13},"geo":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"lang":"en","created_at":{"py/object":"datetime.datetime","__reduce__":[{"py/type":"datetime.datetime"},["B98DGgsvMwAAAA=="]]},"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"place":null,"source":"Twitter for Android"}},"source_url":"http://www.twitter.com","user":{"py/id":1},"geo":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"lang":"en","doc_type":"tweet","created_at":{"py/object":"datetime.datetime","__reduce__":[{"py/type":"datetime.datetime"},["B98EAQIRJgAAAA=="]]},"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"place":null,"source":"Twitter for Windows Phone"}}]}
```

Approach 1:

Here is the command:

```
curl -d @db.json -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/cwc15/_bulk_docs
```

I get below error:

```
{"error":"not_found","reason":"no_db_file"}
```

I did follow below post before I am posting this problem -

```
https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F26264647%2Fcouchdb-exported-file-wont-import-back-into-database&ei=8GMbVY3eNNjo8AW18YL4BA&usg=AFQjCNHdm1o0NS49nKPrEl0zU-n7eVRv8Q&bvm=bv.89744112,d.dGc
```

And I did not get any help from google. The last post I can see over there is way back in 2012, and I couldn't find the help any good. Could someone please help me out. I could be a life saver for me.

Approach 2 -

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:5984/_replicate -d ' {"source": "http://example.com:5984/dbname/", "target": "http://localhost@:5984/dbname/"}'
```

Gave my source and the target where I wanted to copy. In target gave the IP address of that machine followed by port no/dbname/

Got error: `Connection Timedout`

Approach 3:

1. Exported the couch database with filename - cwc15.couch
2. Stored in flash drive.
3. Took root login and went to the location where this file is stored.

Command - `cp cwc15.couch /var/lib/couchdb`

Get error -

```
Error:{{case_clause,{{badmatch,
{error,eaccess}},
    [{couch_file,init,1,
[{file,"couch_file.erl"},{line,314}]},
    {gen_server,init_it,6,
[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},
    {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
        [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,
239}]}]}},
[{couch_server.handle_info,2,
[{file,couch_server.erl"},{line,442}]},
{gen_server,handle_msg,5,
[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,604}]},
{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}

{gen_server,call,
    [couch_server,
    {open,<<"cwc15>>,
      [{user_ctx,
        {user_ctx,null,
          [<<"_admin">>],
           <<"{couch_httpd_auth,
default_authentication_handler}">>}}]},
infinity]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{"error":"not_found","reason":"no_db_file"}` - database doesn't exists, you need to create it first: [1](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/common.html#put--db) Also, don't use `-d` curl key for uploading files: that argument is for sending data in text mode, while binary one (`-T` or `--data-binary`) is what you really want to. JSON is ineed text format, but Unicode data may play devil role here.

For `Connection Timedout` error happened because source or target databases aren't reachable by URLs you'd specified. Not sure what they were in real, but `localhost@:5984` doesn't looks good one. Also, here you didn't create a database again, so initial error may occur.

The error in your logs `{error,eaccess}` means bad file permissions which you accidentally broken with copying a file. Follow [the install instructions](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/install/unix.html#security-considerations) to restore it and ensure that nothing else is broken.

Comment: Thanks bro! I will try the solutions provided.

Comment: So, for the first approach, I got error: curl: Can't open '@db.json'!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information. What could be the issue over here?